# (XCODE) Webview with random url's

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I am creating a webview that will contain different url's. So it will be random when you go to the webview.  But i cant figure out how to do this.  I looked at another question, and got it figured out kinda of. .   This is the question i looked at, [Random websites button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014872/random-websites-button)  I got it working in a webview, instead of safari. But i can't get the webview to work on another view controller now. It only works on the first view controller. I just need to get the webview to work on the other view cotroller. Not for sure if i need a global variable or what.  Here is my code, so you can understand what i'm working with.

```
- (IBAction)site:(id)sender {
    NSArray *urls = @[
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"],
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com"],
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http;//www.yahoo.com"]
                      ];

    int index = arc4random_uniform(urls.count);
    NSURL *randomURL = urls[index];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: randomURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int *randomURL;
        NSString *generatedURL;
        NSArray *urls;
        urls =@[@"http://www.youtube.com",
                @"http://www.twitter.com",
                @"http://www.yahoo.com"];
        randomURL =arc4random()%[urls count];
        generatedURL = [urls objectAtIndex:randomURL];
        NSLog(@"Generated URL = %@", generatedURL);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:generatedURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

You should place the code above in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Thanks alot! Finally got it working, cuz of your help!